# The Swift Programming Language Enumerations Experiment

Tags: xcode, enums, swift

I'm making my way through The Swift Programming Language book, but I'm stuck on an experiment.

I'm given this code:

```
enum Rank: Int {
    case Ace = 1
    case Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten
    case Jack, Queen, King
    func simpleDescription() -> String {
        switch self {
        case .Ace:
            return "Ace"
        case .Jack:
            return "Jack"
        case .Queen:
            return "Queen"
        case .King:
            return "King"
        default:
            return String(self.toRaw())
        }
    }
}
```

For the experiment, I have to "Write a function that compares two Rank values by comparing their raw values.

I had a go:

```
func rankCompare(first: String, second: String) -> String {
    let firstRank = Rank.first
}
```

But I ended up with errors because I don't know how to pass Enum values.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enum values can be passed just like other types. The following function is part of the `Rank` enum and compares one `Rank` to another.

```
func compareToOther(other:Rank) -> Bool {    // other is of type Rank 
        return self.toRaw() == other.toRaw()
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the quick implementation and usage.
[image]

Comment: Ahh okay, so the type is the name of the enum?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass enums by just passing the enum name:

```
// someRank is a Rank enum value
func myFunction (someRank: Rank) -> () {

}
```

And then you can just call it:

```
myFunction(Rank.Ace)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also a beginner, but this is how I worked throughout the experiment.  First I added this;

```
func compareTwoCards(card1: Rank, card2: Rank) -> String {
if card1.toRaw() == card2.toRaw() {
    return "Cards are equal"
} else {
    if card1.toRaw() > card2.toRaw() {
        return "Card1 is greater"
    } else {
        return "Card2 is greater"
    }
} }
```

Then I created two Rank objects

```
let ace = Rank.Ace
let queen = Rank.Queen
```

Finally, I called it three different ways to test it;

```
compareTwoCardsTake2(ace, queen)
compareTwoCardsTake2(queen, ace)
compareTwoCardsTake2(ace, ace)
```

Can some one with more experience please reply if there is a better/more elegant way of performing the compare?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this:

```
func rankCompare(first: Rank, second: Rank) -> String {
    if(first.rawValue > second.rawValue) {
        return "\(first.simpleDescription()) beats \(second.simpleDescription())."
    }
    else if second.rawValue > first.rawValue {
        return "\(second.simpleDescription()) beats \(first.simpleDescription())."
    }
    else {
        return "\(first.simpleDescription()) equals \(second.simpleDescription())."
    }
}

let king = Rank.King
let queen = Rank.Queen
let seven = Rank.Seven
rankCompare(king, queen)
rankCompare(seven, king)
rankCompare(queen, queen)
```

Use .rawValue for doing the comparisons and .simpleDescription() for writing out your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This code can be used to determine if two enumeration values are equal or not. `.toRaw()` is obsolete, so `.rawValue` must be used to obtain the raw value for comparison. An edited version of this function (to make a full comparison with type string information, not just "true" or "false") should be used to complete the exercise. *Hint For Editing: this function is of type Bool.*

```
func compareRanks(rankA: Rank, rankB: Rank) -> Bool {
        return rankA.rawValue == rankB.rawValue
}
```

To see the code and contributors that made this answer possible, please see the question: [Explanation of The Swift Programming Language Enumerations Experiment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45394568/explanation-of-the-swift-programming-language-enumerations-experiment)