# Explanation of The Swift Programming Language Enumerations Experiment

Tags: swift, enums

I first stumbled across this question while researching the same topic:
[The Swift Programming Language Enumerations Experiment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24147060/the-swift-programming-language-enumerations-experiment)

I am researching this, but my problem is that none of the contributors truly explain the mechanics of how their answers manipulate the data from the enumeration. Also, the top answer seems to be outdated, wrong, etc. Perhaps I am missing something because I am just learning this language. If so, can someone explain what I am missing or offer an alternative answer with more detail?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you don't understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
enum Rank: Int {
    case Ace = 1
    case Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten
    case Jack, Queen, King
    func simpleDescription() -> String {
        switch self {
        case .Ace:
            return "Ace"
        case .Jack:
            return "Jack"
        case .Queen:
            return "Queen"
        case .King:
            return "King"
        default:
            return String(self.toRaw())
        }
    }
}
```

This is the enumeration defined in the question. Upon looking at the definition, you can see its raw value will be an integer. There are two requirements for the raw values

1) Raw values can be strings, characters, or any of the integer or floating-point number types.

2) Each raw value must be unique within its enumeration declaration.

In the example, you can see the enumeration case of `Ace` is assigned a raw value of 1 which conforms to the type defined in the enum definition. Since the rest of the cases do not have a raw value defined, Swift will intelligantly assign a raw value, having each case one more than the previous one. In this case, since the first case was explicitly stated with 1, the subsequent cases will be 2,3,etc. 
If the first case was not explicitly stated, it will be assigned a value of 0 and the the following cases will all increment that raw value.

When passing enumerations around your programs, you can use their types rather than their raw values.

```
compareRanks(rankA: Rank, rankB: Rank)
```

Enumerations have a property called `rawValue` which will return the raw value associated with the enum case. Therefore in the code example you linked, using this value allows you to compare two enums to determine if their ranks are equal or not.

```
func compareRanks(rankA: Rank, rankB: Rank) -> Bool {
        return rankA.rawValue == rankB.rawValue
}
```

In previous versions of Swift, there was a method called `toRaw()` which returned the raw value but now, `rawValue` is a property that will return the raw value

Comment: `toRaw()` is a Swift 1 function, no longer available, and that's probably part of the reason that the OP is confused about the other answers.

Comment: okay I will replace with the most up to date rawValue property

Comment: This is a very thorough answer, it explains much of what is implied when using Swift. It is very helpful to anyone not quite familiar with what Swift can assume for the programmer, or anyone not quite ready to track those assumed qualities.